# Браузер не отображает форму

Tags: php

Только изучаю пхп, вот такой код в файле formtest.php, кодировка utf-8

```
<?php //formtest.php
echo "
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Form Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="formtest.php" />
        Как вас зовут?
        <input type="test" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Подтвердить" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
"
?>
```

почему браузер отображает код, а не форму?
<img src="http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/74907917.png">

Comment: PHP включить забыли. Это не бинарник же)

Comment: Что я забыла сделать? Поясните, пожалуйста. Я новичек.

Comment: @Heidel, для работы php надо установить в первую очередь сервер. Для новичков лучше ставить готовую сборку - [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html), например. Ну и ищите справку по этому поводу. Плюс - в коде косяк, подсветка хэшкода вам его любезно выделила) (кавычки в кавчках надо экранировать слэшем **\\**)

Comment: @Sh4dow, вы специально правильный ответ разбиваете на несколько частей и пишете в комментариях к разным ответам? ))

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, у меня 404 ответа, пока не хочу портить))

Comment: А, блин, спасибо, я пыталась открыть файл просто в браузере, а не через сервер, понятно, что он не работал как надо.
Спасибо!

Comment: а как в html коде нужно записать пхп-переменную, чтобы она отобразилась?
как в строке Вас зовут: "$name"<br />

    <?php //formtest.php
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) $name = $_POST['name'];
    else $name = "(Не введено)";
    echo '
    <html>
 <head>
  <title> Form Test </title>
 </head>
 <body>
 Вас зовут: "$name"<br />
 <form method="post" action="formtest.php" />
  Как вас зовут?
  <input type="test" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Подтвердить" />
 </form>
 </body>
       </html>
    '
    ?>

Comment: Нашла вот такой способ
    Вас зовут: "'.$name.'" <br />

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у Вас не правильное использование функции `echo`:

```
<?php
   echo '<p>Hello World!</p>';
?>
```

Comment: **Это** не заработает нигде.

Comment: @Sh4dow, Поясние пожалуйста...

Comment: @niki-timofe,

    <?php // неверный открывающий тег
    echo '<p>Hello World!</p>'; // скобки в эхо - стиль php 3
    ?>

Comment: Спасибо, исправлю. А вообще, я [тут][1] не причём XD

[1]: http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl1_2.php

Comment: @niki-timofe

> Оправдывают свое невежество неискусством учителей только те, которые сами из себя ничего не умеют сделать и все ждут, чтобы их тащили за уши туда, куда они сами должны идти.

*Н. Добролюбов*

Начинайте потихоньку читать исходники серьезных проектов) И еще - php4 вышел 12 лет назад, php5 - 8 лет назад.

Answer (score 0):

Вы поднимали это на локальном сервере типа денвер? если нет, то работать это у вас не будет.

Comment: Файл formtest.php лежит на локальном сервере (опенсервер).

Comment: тогда у вас просто не правильно расставлены кавычки. внутри не могут быть 2е кавычки только одинарные

Comment: Ну люди, ну вы чего =/ PHP из-за ошибок никогда не выдавал исходники. Либо сервер выключен, либо не настроен, либо в httpd.conf надо добавить 

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

Comment: <?php //formtest.php
echo "
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Form Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='formtest.php' method='post' />
        Как вас зовут?
        <input type='text' name='name' />
        <input type='submit' value='Подтвердить' />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
";
?>